# After loading local page in Jquery dialog the parent window loads the same local page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog, jquery-load

My site is written in C# with ASP.NET, all pages being loaded are .aspx pages.

I'm using a button

```
<input type="button" onclick="FindBuilding()">
```

to trigger a javascript function

```
function FindBuilding() {
$('#BuildingPopup).load('./BuildingPopup.aspx?lid=xxx');
$('#BuildingPopup).dialog('open');
}
```

that opens a modal dialog I've created

```
$("#BuildingPopup").dialog({
    modal: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    position: "center",
    resizable: false,
    height: 671,
    width: 1042,
    stack: true
});
```

The dialog is created inside `$(document).ready` function

**The Problem:**

**After the dialog loads BuildingPopup.aspx the parent page then loads the same page** -- this happens anytime I try to load **any** page in a modal dialog, regardless of content. BuildingPopup.aspx is just an example.

**What I have tried to fix it:**

I have tried creating the dialog first, then loading the page using the `open` button. I have also tried using an `iframe` which **works** but the pages never display well and it's a hassle/bad fix.

**Some clues?**

- Some of the pages are calling a web service through AJAX during page load
- The problem persists on pages with and without updatepanels
- Some pages are evaluating code blocks during page load

**UPDATE**

I have discovered that the problem occurs when an updatepanel on the parent page updates.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

This occurs when an `<asp:Timer>` executes an OnTick() method in the codebehind(to update the panel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuns out I just needed to phrase my question better -- I finally found someone else who was having the same problem as me.

**Answer was found here: [UpdatePanel within jQuery.load()-ed content breaks out of the page on postback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16716986/1469797)**

In a nutshell the problem was that using .load was pulling in extra tags from the loaded page that was breaking the HTML on the parent page. `<head> <title> etc` were being pulled into the parent page and causing the problems.

**To fix the problem all that was needed was to specify what content I wanted to pull from the loaded page using `.load(/loadedpage.aspx #content)` instead of pulling the whole page.**

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I had the same problem as this, and I solved it by using update panels for any code that required a callback, not sure why that would not work...