# UpdatePanel within jQuery.load()-ed content breaks out of the page on postback

Tags: c#, jquery, updatepanel, postback

As a preface to my situation, it should be noted that I am using ASP.NET (C#) and jQuery.

So, here's the layout: I have a top div (header/menu) that spans the entire horizontal length of the page. Under this header/menu, I have 2 other divs. The left div is a navigation div with links to pages. The right div is a display div for the pages loaded by Ajax from the links in the left div.

Let's see if I can draw this out...

```
=====================================================
= Top Div              (header/menu)                =
=====================================================
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
= Left Div      =  Right Div                        =
= (Navigation)  =  id = "rightdiv"                  =
=               =  (Displays content loaded by      =
=               =   Ajax from the links in the      =
=               =   left div)                       =
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
=               =                                   =
=====================================================
```

Up to this point, everything works fine. I can click links in the left div and load them in the right div using jQuery... `$('#rightdiv').load('pagenamehere.aspx');`.

**Here's the problem...**

The pages I'm loading into the right div contain an UpdatePanel (1 per page). When clicking the button within the UpdatePanel (which should only refresh the content in the UpdatePanel itself), it instead pulls the content out of the right div (it actually goes to that page) and refreshes the content in the UpdatePanel as if I had visited that page itself and pressed the button.

**My question is...**

How can I prevent this and have the UpdatePanel work on a page brought in using Ajax?

**Here's some additional (weird) information...**

I display the original time the overall layout was loaded ('5/23/2013 10:15:11 AM').

I Ajax in a page to the right div and display the time it was loaded (on that page itself but outside of the UpdatePanel) ('5/23/2013 10:15:17 AM'). This shows that I clicked a page link in the left div a few seconds after the layout loaded.

When I hit the button to refresh the UpdatePanel, it shows me the time when I hit the button inside of the UpdatePanel itself ('5/23/2013 10:15:28 AM'). At this point, it pulls the page out from the right div (as if I were to go to this page from the beginning) and it keeps the original DateTime that this page was loaded into the right div ('5/23/2013 10:15:17 AM').

=====

I've tried every way shape and form to modify the UpdatePanel and ScriptManager to try and keep it from doing this, but to no avail.

I've even tried putting the UpdatePanel around the right div instead of on every single content page (so that pages loaded using Ajax would only refresh that div when posting back).

I'm sure there's a way to have an UpdatePanel on a page loaded via Ajax, but I cannot seem to find a working example or an answer for this anywhere.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

We do not want searches made in the left div (brought in by Ajax) to be lost when content in the right div does a PostBack (hence needing the UpdatePanel). If it did PostBack from the right div, the entire layout would be refreshed instead of just the content in the right div.

**EDIT 2:**

I should clarify that this is only a simple example of what we're trying to accomplish. We want the content in the right div (an entire .aspx page) to PostBack, but only within an UpdatePanel. We need this capability so that the whole layout (top div, left div, and right div) does not refresh on the right div page's PostBack.

Basically, we need to be able to PostBack in the right div without changing the top and left divs. When we bring the right page in via Ajax, the UpdatePanel on the right page does not seem to respect the layout and breaks out of it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your HTML is being broken by loading a complete page. Even though .load() will strip out certain HTML elements, it might be inserting an extra <title> tag, etc.

Here is a simple example with two files.

**to-be-loaded.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>To Be Loaded</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="my-div"></div>
  <script>
    $("#my-div").load('/load-me.html #load-me ul');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**load-me.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Load Me</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="load-me">
  <ul>
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After the load call executes, the div#my-div will contain the contents of the unordered list from load-me.html.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! I removed the <html>, <head> and <body> tags from the included pages. The first time I hit the button on the page loaded with Ajax, it works, but additional clicks give me this error: "Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted." If I load a different page from the left div (or the same one again) it works on every click! So, the question now is... why does it work once then only work again once I load/re- another page?

Comment: Progress is always good news :) You actually can actually load an entire document as the source, but you will generally target a specific element "id" within that document itself to become a part of the target document.

Comment: I've updated the `$('#rightdiv').load('pagenamehere.aspx #content');` to just load the content div. If I put this div outside the <form> tag, the button's PostBack breaks out of the layout again. If I put the content div inside the <form> tag, the button completely makes the page in the right div disappear. Two steps forward, one step back. The only thing that seems to work is to remove the <html>, <head>, and <body> tags from the content pages, but then I still get these odd errors that I can't get past on the second button click (until I load a new page).

Comment: I've found that the UpdatePanel will only work when the form on the content page (brought in by Ajax) does not have a ViewState (except for the very first button click). If I load a different page from the left div or reload the currently loaded page (after clicking the button the very first time), it will work and the form for the right div will not have a ViewState. I've set the form on the content page to enableviewstate="false", but this does not stop it from having a ViewState the very first time. Reloading the page does get rid of this.

Comment: Seems like there could be some issues with the .NET code affecting the jQuery. I've never done any .NET development so I won't be any help there. In practice, I don't personally use jQuery.load, since I tend towards explicit AJAX requests (i.e., jQuery.ajax call) and updating the DOM in the success function. That way you can control whats being loaded with the request.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I can't be sure what is happening without debuging, but maybe you should consider a different approach.

For example, why aren't you loading a right div with update panel as well?

or

why aren't you loading part of right panel with update panel, with another jquery ajax load?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my main post: We do not want searches made in the left div (brought in by Ajax) to be lost when content in the right div does a PostBack (hence needing the UpdatePanel). If it did PostBack from the right div, the entire layout would be refreshed instead of just the content in the right div.

Comment: OK, since you are using Asp.Net you can probaby add OnClientClick="DoJQueryAjaxLoad(); return false;", on the loaded button in the right div. This way a button should not fire postback, and function DoJQueryAjaxLoad can load content using ajax instead of update panel.

Comment: The content in the right div is an entire .aspx page (loaded via Ajax). We need it to PostBack but only within an UpdatePanel. We need it to function this way so that it does not PostBack the entire layout (top div, left div, and right div).